# What is the effect of maxItemsPerTask in ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

MSDN defines `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` `maxItemsPerTask` as

> *maxItemsPerTask*
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The maximum number of tasks to process for each underlying scheduled task used by the pair.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194750(v=vs.110).aspx.

But I don't understand this definition.

What would actually happen if I set this (e.g. to `5`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` will allow for the [creation of up to `maxConcurrencyLevel` concurrent tasks](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.cs,321) (or a single exclusive one) that each handles up to `maxItemsPerTask` tasks and then completes, or as the reference source explains it:

```
/// <summary>The maximum number of tasks we can process before recycling our runner tasks.</summary>
private readonly int m_maxItemsPerTask;
```

A task processing concurrent tasks [can be stopped before reaching `maxItemsPerTask` if there's an exclusive task waiting to be processed](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.cs,430) but not the other way around so `maxItemsPerTask` can be used to throttle exclusive tasks to prevent starvation of concurrent ones.